# How to remove 'selected' attribute from item in ModelChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-forms

ModelChoiceField adds attribute `selected` in HTML, if object from choices list has FK to parent object.

How\where can I remove this 'selected' attribute in order to get just list of choices? Want to mention, that I need to remove just 'selected' attribute, i.e the value itself should not be removed from the list of choices. I need to hook it somehow from python side, not from HTML. I tried to find needed atribute in different places inside `form`, but no luck.

Does anyone know the part of Django code, where there is a check if an object from choices list has FK to parent model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know would it work or not, but an idea would be clear for you.

So, i found source of `Select` widget that sets your `selected` property in html. It's [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Select), just search for `selected_html`.

You can try to subclass `Select` widget:

```
from django.forms.widgets import Select

class CustomSelect(Select):
    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        if option_value is None:
            option_value = ''
        option_value = force_text(option_value)
        if option_value in selected_choices:
            selected_html = ''  # make it empty string like in else statement or refactor all that method
            if not self.allow_multiple_selected:
                # Only allow for a single selection.
                selected_choices.remove(option_value)
        else:
            selected_html = ''
        return format_html('<option value="{}"{}>{}</option>', option_value, selected_html, force_text(option_label))
```

And then in forms

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    your_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=CustomSelect())
    ...
```

It's just solution that i came up with, and i know that this is not so elegant, but it seems that there is no simple way to disable that `selected` thing.

Comment: It works) Just before you posted, I found the needed code in Django sources and checked :)

Comment: @TitanFighter glad that helped.:)